# Access Google Drive Application Data Folder Cross-Platform App

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have an app to which I'd like to add cloud sync for the application's data files.

The desktop version of the app is written in Java and runs on Windows, OSX, and Linux. mobile version is an Android app. To further complicate matters, the Android app is available in two versions, free and paid, with different package names.

Google Drive API allows files to be stored and manipulated in an application data folder. Is it possible for all of the above versions of the app to share the same application directory? What exactly constitutes an "application"?

If the Android app is uninstalled, will the application folder be removed?

Answer (score 1):

A drive app is distinct from an android/desktop/web app.  All of those can use the same drive app.  The drive app is the entry in the developer console.  Just use the same developer console app id and credentials in all your variants.